# Updating all entries in a column based on matching from another SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables

**TableA**:

```
 Student ID| Student Name| DOB
 ------------------------------
 1         | Alex        |
 2         | Amanda      |
 3         | Anatoly     |
```

**TableB**:

```
 Student ID| DOB
 ------------------------
 1         | 2/2/2004
 3         | 3/7/2004
 6         | 1/8/2004
```

Can I use a SQL `Update` statement to populate `TableA`'s `DOB` column based on matching entries in `TableB`?

That is, `TableA` after update should look like this

**TableA**:

```
 Student ID| Student Name| DOB
 --------------------------------------
 1         | Alex        | 2/2/2004
 2         | Amanda      |
 3         | Anatoly     | 3/7/2004
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this.

```
update a
set DOB = b.DOB
from TableA a
join TableB b on b.StudentID = a.StudentID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE
    TableA
SET
    TableA.DOB = TableB.DOB
FROM
    TableA
INNER JOIN
   TableB
ON 
    TableA.StudentID = TableB.StudentID
```

You can also do it with aliases as shown above.

Comment: This approach will work with a couple of caveats. TableA must be FROM table and TableA may not be referenced more than once in the query. If either of those are not met you will get unexpected results.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx "If the object being updated is the same as the object in the FROM clause and there is only one reference to the object in the FROM clause, an object alias may or may not be specified. If the object being updated appears more than one time in the FROM clause, one, and only one, reference to the object must not specify a table alias. All other references to the object in the FROM clause must include an object alias."